# Setfacl configuration issue in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, access-control-list

I am configuring a Linux Server with ACL[Access Control Lists]. It is not allowing me to perform setfacl operation on one of the directoriy /xfiles. I am able to perform the setfacl on other directories as `/tmp /op/applocal/`.

I am getting the error as :

```
root@asifdl01devv # setfacl -m   user:eqtrd:rw-,user:feedmgr:r--,user::---,group::r--,mask:rw-,other:--- /xfiles/change1/testfile
setfacl: /xfiles/change1/testfile: Operation not supported
```

I have defined my /etc/fstab as

```
/dev/ROOTVG/rootlv      /                       ext3    defaults        1 1
/dev/ROOTVG/varlv       /var                    ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/ROOTVG/optlv       /opt                    ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/ROOTVG/crashlv     /var/crash              ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/ROOTVG/tmplv       /tmp                    ext3    defaults        1 2
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/dev/ROOTVG/swaplv      swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
/dev/APPVG/home      /home            ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/APPVG/archives      /archives            ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/APPVG/test      /test            ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/APPVG/oracle      /opt/oracle            ext3    defaults        1 2
/dev/APPVG/ifeeds      /xfiles            ext3    defaults        1 2
```

I have a solaris server where the vfstab is defined as

```
cat vfstab

#device         device          mount           FS      fsck    mount   mount
#to mount       to fsck         point           type    pass    at boot options
#
fd      -       /dev/fd fd      -       no      -
/proc   -       /proc   proc    -       no      -
/dev/vx/dsk/bootdg/swapvol      -       -       swap    -       no      -
swap    -       /tmp    tmpfs   -       yes     size=1024m
/dev/vx/dsk/bootdg/rootvol      /dev/vx/rdsk/bootdg/rootvol     /       ufs     1       no      logging
/dev/vx/dsk/bootdg/var  /dev/vx/rdsk/bootdg/var /var    ufs     1       no      logging
/dev/vx/dsk/bootdg/home /dev/vx/rdsk/bootdg/home        /home   ufs     2       yes     logging
/dev/vx/dsk/APP/test        /dev/vx/rdsk/APP/test       /test     vxfs   3       yes     -
/dev/vx/dsk/APP/archives        /dev/vx/rdsk/APP/archives       /archives     vxfs   3       yes     -
/dev/vx/dsk/APP/oracle        /dev/vx/rdsk/APP/oracle       /opt/oracle     vxfs   3       yes     -
/dev/vx/dsk/APP/xfiles    /dev/vx/rdsk/APP/xfiles   /xfiles vxfs   3       yes     -
```

I am not able to find out the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable `acl`s on the mount point. Either remount with the `acl` option or reboot with the `acl` option in the fstab.

You need to first check if your kernel supports the `acl` option - otherwise, the mount may fail.

#### To check if `acl` was compiled into the kernel

```
cat /boot/config-`uname -r` | grep _ACL
```

The 'expected' output should be something like this ..

```
CONFIG_EXT2_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_EXT3_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_EXT4_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_XFS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_NFS_V3_ACL=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V3_ACL=y
CONFIG_NFS_ACL_SUPPORT=m
```

#### To remount without reboot

```
mount -o remount,acl /xfiles
```

#### To mount with `acl` with a reboot/persistent

```
/dev/APPVG/ifeeds      /xfiles            ext3    defaults,acl        1 2
```